# Return type of a lambda function is lambda []X ()->X and can't be converted to X

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, lambda

Consider a class `Point` with a constructor `Point(int _x, int _y, char _ch) :x(_x), y(_y), ch(_ch) {};`, trying to use this class with a lambda function:

```
Point p = [&]() {return Point(1, 2, '%');};
Point p = [&]() -> Point {return Point(1, 2, '%');};
```

Both lead to the error:

> no suitable user-defined conversion from "lambda []Point ()->Point" to "Point" exists

What is this type and how can you make it become `X` instead of `lambda []X ()->X`?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a lambda to a variable of type `Point`? Do you want a `Point`, or do you want a lambda that makes points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of a lambda is not the same as its return type. You're looking to declare the lambda first:

```
auto func = [&]() -> Point {return Point(1, 2, '%');};
```

and then call it:

```
Point p = func();
```

What's more, is that you don't need anything in the capture list (`[&]`) because you're not using any variables in the surrounding scope:

```
auto func = []() -> Point {return Point(1, 2, '%');};
```

The type of a lambda is a compile-time determined type that you cannot know, hence the need for `auto`.

Comment: Oh I thought that being an "anonymous" function you can't actually declare it, probably missed it on sites that explain this too...

Comment: Yes I know about `[&]`, it's just a simple example, in the real lambda function that I use I need `[&]`.

Comment: Some regard it as a misnomer to refer to lambdas as "anonymous functions". They're really just fancy functors that the compiler creates in-place (this is the main reason we can create classes within functions in C++11). So yes, you will actually have an instance of the functor.